# Jenkins - adding a user to a group

Tags: jenkins

We have Jenkins installed and I'm wondering how to add an existing user to a Jenkins group.

I find how-to's for the case where in `Configure Global Security` the `Security Realm` is set to `Jenkins' own user database`. We have set this to `Active Directory` - but maybe this doesn't make a real difference to the problem.

In section `Authorization` we have set `Matrix-based security` and there are already four groups defined from a previous user, those groups have some custom rights set, and a bunch of AD users were added to those group somehow.

My problem: if I try to add a new user, I can add it to the matrix and give him the rights, but I don't see how to simply add the user to the group. I don't want a huge list of users who all have the same rights - I just want them bundled each into one of the four groups. But how can I add a user to a group? It was possible somehow before, as there are obviously users added to those groups.

Maybe a plugin was uninstalled by accident and is missing for this purpose? But I guess that in that case the Matrix-based security wouldn't even be displayed anymore!?

Any help? Thanks.

Comment: What are the 4 groups? Are they AD groups or Jenkins-spexifc groups?

Comment: @IanW I think, the 4 groups were added by some previous users to Jenkins in the matrix-based security and somehow a dozen AD users were added to those 4 groups. Now, I'm in the position to add other AD users to those groups, and I'm failing to do so. There must be some way, cause adding groups without being able to add users to groups doesn't make sense to me - and obviously it was possible somehow as I was also added to one of those groups (the group that is allowed to do everything, but I'm the only one in that group at the moment).

Comment: Add those details to your Q so as to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this specific case the groups are AD groups and the users are added to those groups in the AD, not in Jenkins. So, if you have set the `Security Realm` to `Active Directory` you must add users to groups on the active directory level - not within Jenkins.